# Where does EKS pull app images from by default?

Tags: docker, containers, amazon-eks, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

For EKS internal images including coredns, kubeproxy EKS uses ECR
but what about app images, if it is not explicitly defined on deployment file, what is default source for EKS to pull images from?
I.e. below is nginx deployment, and no explicit registry defined. Where does nginx image come from for this deployment?

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: "1.20"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a **registry** **hostname**, `Kubernetes` assumes that you mean the `Docker public registry`.

Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-names

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `nginx` image would be pulled from Docker Hub.